# Google reCaptcha after x attempts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, recaptcha

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of attaching Google's reCaptcha to a form login after 3 unsuccessful attempts.
How can I attach the reCaptcha once 3 attempts were challenged?

My PHP reCaptcha:

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "MyPublicKey";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
//
}
```

What is the best way to achieve such?
Should I use js for that matter?

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Either user some form of server-side storage (Not session!) to track how many times a specific ip has attempted, or use cookies/session (which would defeat the purpose if the bot doesn't use cookies)

Comment: Add a hidden field, let's assume 'count'..by default set it's value to 1..after every attempt change the value to `$_POST['count']+1` or whichever way is appropriate..and if the value is not set you know it's a bot..still there is chance, as in if the bot posts the form with the count field value as 1 everytime..